# JSF TinyMCE Composite Component not working?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tinymce

I have created a TinyMCE Composite Component 
Steps which i did

**1-** Added `tinymce` folder provided by `TinyMCE` in resource directory of the project.

**2-** Then created another folder `editors` in resource directory and created two file one is js file **tinymce_init.js** and code is

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    theme : "simple",
    debug : true,
    editor_selector : "tinymce"
});
```

and another file **tinymce.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="value" />
    </composite:interface>
    <composite:implementation>
        <h:outputScript library="tinymce" name="tinymce.js" target="head" />
        <h:outputScript library="editors" name="tinymce_init.js" target="head" />
        <h:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="80" />
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

**3-** Now access this composite component into my xhtml file something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:editors="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/editors">
<h:head>
    <title>test</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <editors:tinymce />
</h:body>
</html>
```

But when i access this file i saw a input box without any toolbar , what i am doing wrong and JS is loaded properly without any error in browser console.

Comment: Why tinyMCE? Primefaces `<p:editor/>` is excellent one.

Comment: Yes i want to add code like stackoverflow but i am not able to fix that issue also Editors have lots of complexities for user so i want TinyMCE which is like stakcoverflow editor just simple

Comment: How does your project layout look like? Where are the javascript files placed and so forth.

Comment: Javascript and TincyMce files inside resource folder and i saw Chrome console its loading no any error